# multiple file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Does know how to or can provide a demo or script which will allow multiple files to be uploader to a web server WITHOUT using flash or anything which needs to be installed on the client machine.

Ideally providing a status with how the uploads are doing ie 27% etc.

It would be great if I could select multiple files then hit upload and then they are uploaded one by one in a queue?

Any ideas? Any language is fine.

> Hey - I've spent a lot of time
>   searching through google but from what
>   I can see nobody has done an multiple
>   file uploader with a status with out
>   using
>   flash/uploadify/fanceyupload/SWFUpload
>   without having several input boxes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't provide the status with pure PHP.

AJAX might be a solution or Flash.

Uploading multiple files works pretty similar as uploading one file.
You can send the files in an array.

Comment: for the multiple files, see http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-MultiFile-Upload-Script-in-PHP/
for the dynamic client side with status and progress bar, see javascript, not ajax, no need server connection to add dynamic behavior for uploading files.

Comment: you actually need a server connection, if you want to serve an exact status!

Comment: Hey - I've spent a lot of time searching through google but from what I can see nobody has done an multiple file uploader with a status with out using flash/uploadify/fanceyupload/SWFUpload without having several input boxes.

Comment: Have a look at this for the progress bar: http://blog.joshuaeichorn.com/archives/2005/05/01/ajax-file-upload-progress/

He uses AJAX.

Here is an example for multiple file upload: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-MultiFile-Upload-Script-in-PHP/

Google is full of tutorials;-)

Comment: like I said they are using several input boxes:  devarticles.com/c/a/…

Answer (score 2):

Everybody already answer what's possible or not, a good jquery plugin for multifile upload: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

The simple way: add multiple file input elements.

The not so simple way: use a Javascript framework to achive this. There are [many scripts out](http://www.google.gr/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&rls=en&hs=vxa&q=multiple+file+upload+javascript&btnG=Search) supporting this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible. I hate Flash, but there are two things that are must-do in Flash: (multi)upload with progress bar, and audio/video streaming.
For multiupload with progress bar I suggest using http://www.uploadify.com/ - it's extremely easy to implement :)

Comment: Maybe you should be more precise. Multiple file upload without Flash is easy to do. File upload with progress bar cannot be done with pure JavaScript (no Flash nor Java nor other kind of applet).

Comment: A file upload progress bar can be done in pure JavaScript. You have to make AJAX requests to the server at the same time as the upload is happening to ask it how much of the file it has received so far.

Comment: @PhiLho: is it possible to select multiple files at once to upload? I know you can put many "input type=file" tags, but that is not the way..
@bobince: with php?

Comment: @PhiLho There is no way as far as I know to allow you to upload multiple files at once by way of Ctrl + clicking on all desired files unless you use flash, silverlight, etc. You can only click allow it to upload the file and then choose the next file ...

Answer (score 1):

With the right software on the server, it's possible to display an upload progress meter using just JavaScript on the client. Check out [mod_uploadprogress](http://upload.lighttpd.net/) for lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this must be really late for an answer, but i too was faced with the same upload problem, most depressing was no support for multiple browsers. I found this plugin which worked on almost all the browsers, I hope it does help someone in future.

http://www.uploadify.com/